# I showed that $AX = b_1$ has a unique solution. Does it mean that the columns of $A$ are linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-independence

I know that if $AX = b_1$ has infinite possible solutions, then
$AX = b_1$
$\iff A(X_{inh} + X_{hom}) = b_1$
$\implies "AX_{hom} = 0 $ has infinite possible solutions", thus the columns of $A$ are linearly dependent.

I know I can't imply "$AX_{hom} = 0$ has 1 unique solution $(X_{hom} = 0)$" from "$AX = b_1$ has 1 unique solution", since I only showed it for $b_1$ but not for all all $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$. In other words, what if there is a $b_i$, $i\neq1$, such that $AX_{hom}=0$ has infinite possible solutions?

Intuitively I feel like no such $b_i$ exists. Therefore "$AX = b_1$ has a unique solution" implies "the columns of $A$ are linearly independent". But how do I show it?

Comment: Yes, because if not, there would be a non zero $x^*$ satisfying $A x^* = 0$.

Comment: wait but isn't this circular reasoning? I know that $AX=b_1$ has a unique solution. I don't know yet if 0 is the only solution to $AX = 0$. That's what I'm trying to show

Comment: If $\ Ax^*=0\ $ and $\ x_u\  $ is the unique solution to $\ Ax=b_1\ $, then since $\ A(x_u+x^*)=Ax_u=b_1\ $, $\ x_u+x^*\ $ is also a solution.  It follows from the uniqueness of the solution that $\ x_u+x^*=x_u\ $, and hence that $\ x^*=0\ $.

Comment: yes I have the same reasoning that $X_{hom}$ or $X^* = 0$, for this is only for $b_1$. What if for $b_i$, $i \neq 1$, $AX=b_i$ has infinite possible solutions? Intuitively I think there is no such $b_i$, but how do I show it? @lonzaleggiera

Comment: If $\ x_1\ $ and $\ x_2\ $ are solutions of $\ Ax=b_i\ $, and $\ x_u\ $ is the (unique) solution of $\ Ax=b_1\ $ then $\ A(x_u+x_1-x_2)=b_u+b_i-b_i=b_1\ $, so $\ x_u+x_1-x_2\ $ is a solution of $\ Ax=b_1\ $. It follows from the uniqueness of the solution to this equation that $\ x_u+x_1-x_2=x_u\ $, or, equivalently, $\ x_1=x_2\ $. In other words, $\ x_1\ $ must be the *only* solution of $\ Ax=b_i\ $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can rather work for the contrapositive statement. Suppose columns of $A$ are linearly dependent then $rank(A)<n$, where $n$ is number of columns in $A$ or equivalently number of variables in the system of equations furnished by $AX=b_1$. Now $rank(A)<n$ implies either infinitely many solutions or no solution *i.e.* non-uniqueness in either case.

Comment: don't we have to consider the case when the system is incompatible?

Comment: @Heng Wei...Please elaborate what you meant by an incompatible system.

Comment: in the case $AX=b_1$ has no solutions

Comment: @Heng Wei.......Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

To be more explicit, since we have proved that:

If $A\underline{X}=\underline{b}_1$ has a unique solution,

then $A\underline{X}=\underline{0}$ iff $\underline{X}=\underline{0}$.

We can proceed as follows:

Let $$A= 
\left (\begin{matrix}
\underline{a_1} & \underline{a_2} & \cdots & \underline{a_n} \\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
where $\underline{a_1}, \underline{a_2}, \cdots, \underline{a_n}$ are the column vectors of $A$
and $$\underline{X}=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
\vdots \\
x_n \\
\end{matrix}
\right)$$

Then $$x_1\underline{a_1}+x_2\underline{a_2}+\cdots+x_n\underline{a_n}=\underline{0}$$

$$\implies \left (\begin{matrix}
\underline{a_1} & \underline{a_2} & \cdots & \underline{a_n} \\
\end{matrix}
\right)\left(
\begin{matrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
\vdots \\
x_n \\
\end{matrix}
\right)=\underline{0}$$

$$\implies A\underline{X}=\underline{0}$$

$$\implies \underline{X}=\underline{0}$$

$$\implies x_1=x_2=\cdots=x_n=0$$

Hence $\underline{a_1}, \underline{a_2}, \cdots, \underline{a_n}$ are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can easily show that by assuming that you have two solutions $X_1\ne X_2$, that is, $AX_1=AX_2$. Hence, $A(X_1-X_2)=0$. But if the columns of $A$ are independent, this means that $X_1-X_2$ must be zero and, therefore, $X_1=X_2$.